# What goes in "some-network" placeholder in dockerized redis cli?

Tags: docker, redis

I'm looking at [documentation here](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis), and see the following line:

```
$ docker run -it --network some-network --rm redis redis-cli -h some-redis
```

What should go in the `--network some-network` field?  My docker run command in the field before did default port mapping of `docker run -d -p 6379:6379`, etc.

I'm starting my redis server with default docker network configuration, and see this is in use:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
abcfa8a32de9        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 minutes ago       Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   some-redis
```

However, using the default bridge network produces:

```
$ docker run -it --network bridge --rm redis redis-cli -h some-redis
Could not connect to Redis at some-redis:6379: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore the `--network bridge` command and use:

```
docker exec -it some-redis redis-cli
```

Comment: Downvotes are misplaced.  It was my question and this solved my problem.  The other answers did not.  This is /correct/.

Comment: Agreed! And it's a good question too because the documentation is obviously out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Docker includes support for networking containers through the use of network drivers. By default, Docker provides two network drivers for you, the bridge and the overlay drivers. You can also write a network driver plugin so that you can create your own drivers but that is an advanced task.

Read more here.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/

Answer (score -1):

You need to run

```
docker network create some-network
```

It doesn't matter what name `some-network` is, just so long as the Redis server, your special CLI container, and any clients talking to the server all use the same name.  (If you're using Docker Compose this happens for you automatically and the network will be named something like `directoryname_default`; use `docker network ls` to find it.)

If your Redis server is already running, you can use [docker network connect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) to attach the existing container to the new network.  This is one of the few settings you're able to change after you've created a container.

If you're just trying to run a client to talk to this Redis, you don't need Docker for this at all.  You can install the Redis client tools locally and run `redis-cli`, pointing at your host's IP address and the first port in the `docker run -p` option.  The Redis wire protocol is simple enough that you can also use primitive tools like `nc` or `telnet` as well.